# textbox and label won't hide during page_load

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to hide  the object `txtDisc` when `lblUserType` is not the string **special_user**. `lblLock` is *Locked* and visible when `txtDisc` visibility is false, and vice versa.

So I put it inside the page_Load but the method won't function at all.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    buttonVisibility();
}

private void buttonVisibility()
{
    if (lblUserType.Text == "special_user")
    {
        txtDisc.Visible = true;
        lblLock.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint, inspect `lblUserType.Text`.

Comment: @CodeCaster breakpoint?

Comment: [MSDN: Using Breakpoints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your code to :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
    { 
        buttonVisibility();
    }
}

private void buttonVisibility()
{
    if (lblUserType.Text == "special_user")
    {
        txtDisc.Visible = true;
        lblLock.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        txtDisc.Visible = false;
        lblLock.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

By using if (Page.IsPostBack == false) we are sure that the code inside will only be executed at the first page load. IsPostBack is a property of the Asp.Net page that tells whether or not the page is on its initial load or if a user has perform a button on your web page that has caused the page to post back to itself

Comment: Please explain what you changed and why that would solve the problem.

Comment: By using if (Page.IsPostBack == false) we are sure that the code inside will only be executed at the first page load.

IsPostBack is a property of the Asp.Net page that tells whether or not the page is on its initial load or if a user has perform a button on your web page that has caused the page to post back to itself

Comment: @BeldiAnouar it is not working.The **lblLock** is still visible and the **txtDisc** is still not visible.

Comment: \RaNalasa  I edit my answer for you ,test and mark answer please

Comment: @CodeCaster  ok i have edit my answer for explaining my solution for other user

Comment: @CodeCaster I do refresh the page please and return back your up vote please

Answer (score 0):

You are using only an if condition in your code, but if the condition is not true, what actions should be taken? So because of this, add an else block in your condition

Try this code:

```
private void buttonVisibility()
{
    if (lblUserType.Text == "special_user")
    {
        txtDisc.Visible = true;
        lblLock.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        txtDisc.Visible = false;
        lblLock.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Try this" is not an answer. Explain what problem you perceived, what changes you suggest and why that would solve the problem.

Comment: rai nalasa you can try my answer